# SharedPreferences helper class

Tags: java, android

I am doing SharedPreferences helper class to make my code looks nice.

```
public class SharedPreferencesHelper {
    Context context;

    public SharedPreferencesHelper(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean isLogged(String prefs){
        return context.getSharedPreferences(prefs,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                      .getBoolean("LOGGED",false);
    }

    public void setLogged(String prefs){
        context.getSharedPreferences(prefs,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
               .edit().putBoolean("LOGGED",true).apply();
    }
}
```

The question is should I make these methods static and initialize SharedPreferences in each method or better to left it not static and call SharedPreferencesHelper class once from my other classes? Thanks

Comment: Does it make any difference if you make it static or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't keep a reference to the context. I would rather keep the `SharedPreference` and its `Editor` as static member of your helper class. This way you won't need to instantiate `SharedPreferencesHelper` every time you need to read/write the `SharedPreference`. One step further would use the Application `Context` (with a your custom Application subclass) to initialize both `SharedPreference` and `Editor`, the first time you access the helper itself. That's how I would shape it

Comment: using dagger2 and having singleton would help. and you can inject share preferences wherever you want

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for the hint. I never used Dagger, so I am kind of blind there. About the singleton, I don't see the necessity. In the end op wants to expose methods to write in read from the sharedpreference

Comment: @AntonKazakov  an example of how I usually do it is [here](https://github.com/bblackbelt/ShutterStockClient/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/shutterstock/android/shutterstock/utilities/SSSharedPreferences.java)

Comment: @Blackbelt just tried this code and it thrown NPE on sSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("USER_PREFERENCES", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE); I copied Application class  and helper class from your github.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105882/discussion-between-anton-kazakov-and-blackbelt).

Comment: did you subclass Application and register it in the AndroidManifest ? (I can't do chat - sorry) ?

Comment: @Blackbelt sorry my bad. Forget to do it :) Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

Use this  :

```
public class SharedPreferencesHelper {

public static final String FILE_NAME = "APP_PREFERENCES";

  public static void put(Context context, String key, Object object) {

    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME,  Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    if (object instanceof String) {
        editor.putString(key, (String) object);
    } else if (object instanceof Integer) {
        editor.putInt(key, (Integer) object);
    } else if (object instanceof Boolean) {
        editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) object);
    } else if (object instanceof Float) {
        editor.putFloat(key, (Float) object);
    } else if (object instanceof Long) {
        editor.putLong(key, (Long) object);
    } else {
        editor.putString(key, object.toString());
    }
    SharedPreferencesCompat.apply(editor);
}

   public static Object get(Context context, String key, Object defaultObject) {

    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (defaultObject instanceof String) {
        return sp.getString(key, (String) defaultObject);
    } else if (defaultObject instanceof Integer) {
        return sp.getInt(key, (Integer) defaultObject);
    } else if (defaultObject instanceof Boolean) {
        return sp.getBoolean(key, (Boolean) defaultObject);
    } else if (defaultObject instanceof Float) {
        return sp.getFloat(key, (Float) defaultObject);
    } else if (defaultObject instanceof Long) {
        return sp.getLong(key, (Long) defaultObject);
    }

    return null;
}

public static void remove(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.remove(key);
    SharedPreferencesCompat.apply(editor);
}

public static void clear(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.clear();
    SharedPreferencesCompat.apply(editor);
}

public static boolean contains(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.contains(key);
}

public static Map<String, ?> getAll(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.getAll();
}



private static class SharedPreferencesCompat {
    private static final Method sApplyMethod = findApplyMethod();

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    private static Method findApplyMethod() {
        try {
            Class clz = SharedPreferences.Editor.class;
            return clz.getMethod("apply");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void apply(SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        try {
            if (sApplyMethod != null) {
                sApplyMethod.invoke(editor);
                return;
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        editor.commit();


    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use static class if `Context` was a "global" context and obtaining values from the context was gruesomely long and (kinda) evil. That way, getting the value from the static class will be easier without having you to make mistake repeatingly doing the same operation all over your code space without making an error.

And as for turning your `SharedPreferencesHelper` static, a good approach:

```
public class SharedPreferencesHelper {

    private SharedPreferencesHelper(Context context){
    }

    private static void ensureNotNull(Context context) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context is null.");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLogged(Context context, String prefs){
        ensureNotNull(context);
        return context.getSharedPreferences(prefs,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                      .getBoolean("LOGGED",false);
    }

    public static void setLogged(Context context, String prefs){
        ensureNotNull(context);
        context.getSharedPreferences(prefs,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
               .edit().putBoolean("LOGGED",true).apply();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with singleton pattern, keeping only one instance at the time:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

public class SharedPrefsUtil {
    private static SharedPrefsUtil instance;
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "default_preferences";

    public synchronized static SharedPrefsUtil getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SharedPrefsUtil();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private SharedPrefsUtil() {
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(@NonNull Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getBoolean("LOGGED", false);
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(@NonNull Context context, boolean value) {
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putBoolean("LOGGED", value).apply();
    }
}
```

Note the same singleton could be easily achieved using [Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/) library.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
object SharedPreferenceHelper {
    private val PREF_FILE = "SharedPreference"

    enum class StringValues(val defValue: String) {
        Test1("");

        fun set(context: Context, value: String) {
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(name, value).apply()
        }

        fun get(context: Context): String? = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(name, defValue)
    }

    enum class IntValues(val defValue: Int) {
        Test1(0);

        fun set(context: Context, value: Int) {
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt(name, value).apply()
        }

        fun get(context: Context): Int = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(name, defValue)
    }

    enum class LongValues(val defValue: Long) {
        Test1(0);

        fun set(context: Context, value: Long) {
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putLong(name, value).apply()
        }

        fun get(context: Context): Long = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getLong(name, defValue)
    }

    enum class FloatValues(val defValue: Float) {
        Test1(0f);

        fun set(context: Context, value: Float) {
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putFloat(name, value).apply()
        }

        fun get(context: Context): Float = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getFloat(name, defValue)
    }

    enum class BooleanValues(val defValue: Boolean) {
        Test1(true);

        fun set(context: Context, value: Boolean) {
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(name, value).apply()
        }

        fun get(context: Context): Boolean = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(name, defValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not created another class but I am using GenericActivity concept and I have created the function inside the BaseActivity class which extends AppCompatActivity and my all Activities extends Base Activity.

```
//This is the function to Set or Put values in sharedPref : Kotlin

fun putToSharedPref(key: String, value: Any) {
        val editor =  getSharedPreferences(Constants.appName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
        when (value) {
            is String -> {
                editor.putString(key,value)
            }
            is Int -> {
                editor.putInt(key,value)
            }
            is Float -> {
                editor.putFloat(key,value)
            }
            is Long -> {
                editor.putLong(key,value)
            }
            is Boolean -> {
                editor.putBoolean(key,value)
            }
        }
        editor.apply()
    }

//This function are for getting the value from shared pref.

fun getSharedPrefBoolean(key: String, default: Boolean) : Boolean {
        return getSharedPreferences(Constants.appName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(key,default)
    }

    fun getSharedPrefInt(key: String, default: Int) : Int {
        return getSharedPreferences(Constants.appName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(key,default)
    }

    fun getSharedPrefString(key: String, default: String) : String? {
        return getSharedPreferences(Constants.appName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(key,default)
    }

    fun getSharedPrefFloat(key: String, default: Float) : Float {
        return getSharedPreferences(Constants.appName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getFloat(key,default)
    }

    fun getSharedPrefLong(key: String, default: Long) : Long {
        return getSharedPreferences(Constants.appName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getLong(key,default)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a class with the name of SharedPreferencesHelper like this

```
public class SharedPreferencesHelper {
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public SharedPreferencesHelper(Context context, String preferenceFileName) {
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(preferenceFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void setString(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public String getString(String key) {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "abc");
}

public void setInt(String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public int getInt(String key) {
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 1);
} }
```

You can use this class like this

```
private SharedPreferencesHelper prefs = new SharedPreferencesHelper(requireContext(), "my_preferences");

//for string value
prefs.setString("keyString","hi");
prefs.getString("keyString");

//for int value
prefs.setInt("keyInt",2);
prefs.getInt("keyInt");
```

Answer (score -1):

Here this class is help you.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
//import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class SharedPreference {

    private static SharedPreference   sharedPreference;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "AOP_PREFS";
    public static final String PREFS_KEY = "AOP_PREFS_String";



    public static SharedPreference getInstance()
    {
        if (sharedPreference == null)
        {
            sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
        }
        return sharedPreference;
    }

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }

    public void save(Context context, String text , String Key) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
        editor = settings.edit(); //2

        editor.putString(Key, text); //3

        editor.commit(); //4
    }

    public String getValue(Context context , String Key) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        String text = "";
      //  settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        text = settings.getString(Key, "");
        return text;
    }

    public void clearSharedPreference(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void removeValue(Context context , String value) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        editor.remove(value);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

You can get value like this.

```
String KeeLogin = SharedPreference.getInstance().getValue(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_KEY");
```

And Store data Like this

```
SharedPreference.getInstance().save(LoginScreen.this,"VALUE","YOUR_KEY");
```

Hope its help you :)