# using shared preference in android trying to save a string but getting error as null point exception on a null object

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

using shared preference in android trying to save a string from  main activity and trying to get the sharedpreference string from another activity.
thanks in advance.

```
Gcm.setGCM("some text to save");
```

but getting error as:

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.putString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object
```

Gcm.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Gcm {

    public static SharedPreferences pref;
    private static Context ctx;

    public Gcm(Context context){

        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("gcm", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ctx = context;
    }


    public static String getGCM(){
        return pref.getString("gcmid", "none");

    }


    public static void setGCM(String gcmid)
    {
        System.out.println("gcmid->"+gcmid);
        pref.edit().putString("gcmid", gcmid).commit();
    }

    public static void removeGCM(){

        pref.edit().putString("gcmid", "none").commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: yes I am sure.@jdabrowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a static method from the class Gcm without creating an instance of that class. That way the constructor of Gcm is never called which leads to a NullPointerException because `pref` in `setGCM()` is never instantiated.

You either do

```
Gcm mGcm = new Gcm(context);
mGcm.setGcm("some text to safe");
```

Or you write that class as a singleton and do

```
Gcm.getInstance().setGcm("some text to safe");
```

If you don't know how to write a singleton, google will help. It's a common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Check here my answer.

[SharedPreferences helper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912227/sharedpreferences-helper-class/35912608#35912608)

Its helper class for Sharedpreferences.

Comment: This helper class might be useful but I think it's more important to explain what he or she is doing wrong first.

Answer (score 0):

Update below method:

```
public static void setGCM(String gcmid)
{
 System.out.println("gcmid->"+gcmid);
  if(pref==null){
    pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences("gcm", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  }
 pref.edit().putString("gcmid", gcmid).commit();
}
```

Hope this will help you