# Save input text and use same text as checkbox label in another activity

Tags: android, checkbox, textbox

In my android app, I want to provide a text box to input a name and save it. Later I want to retrieve the text as checkbox label in other activity. So.. how can I do it? Like multiple names will generate multiple checkbox in next activity..

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Where u store this name?

Comment: In their mobile itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store such data in `SharedPreferences`, see this guide:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

So in your case:

1) Get data from `EditText`:

```
EditText etTextInput = findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);
String text = etTextInput.getText().toString();
```

2) Write to Shared Preferences:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "preference_file_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("key_my_text", text);
editor.commit();
```

3) Retrieve from Shared Preferences in another Activity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "preference_file_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String text = sharedPref.getString("key_my_text", "default_value");
```

4) Set text to your `CheckBox`:

```
CheckBox checkbox = findViewById(R.id.my_ checkbox);
checkbox.setText(text);
```

Note this is very simplified, you can i.e. create a Shared Preferences helper class as per this question and answers: [SharedPreferences helper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912227/sharedpreferences-helper-class)

Comment: Ok that's cool.. so I can save the names in SharedPreferences

Comment: You can save all primitive data types in SharedPreferences and even more. For more complex data it's better to use database, but it's not your case now. Please upvote & accept answer if it is helpful for you.

Comment: For database again we have to make the app an online stuff.. which I'm trying to make all of it offline.. so what do u say? Better to have a database?

Comment: If you have more complex data, definitely better to use SQLite or Room database then Shared Preferences.